# no bootable medium found system halted

Tags: server, software-center, virtualbox, boot-failure

When  open ubuntu on virtual box , it doesn't work , and the following *message* appear 
"**No bootable medium found system halted**"

How i can solve this problm?

Thanks

Comment: What OS have you installed in VirtualBox?

Comment: do you mean version of ubuntu ? if that ubuntu 11.04

Comment: You have installed it already inside VirtualBox?

Comment: yes i installed it

Comment: look under the machine settings --> boot order.

Comment: the boot order is : hard disk then cd/dvd rom then floppy then network

Comment: Under Storage Host Drive, what is the status of pass through?

Comment: oh .. i found it empty! i specified the location of the source again .                                                                               Thanks Mitch for your help :)

Comment: Which one worked?

Comment: in setting > storage > ide cotrollere is empty , soi specified the location of the source again(a compressed file which contain ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: @alsadi90: did that solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

This error is thrown by what you might call the "BIOS" of VirtualBox. There should be a button you can press during startup to select a boot device. If this doesn't work, you might want to try reinstalling.

If grub2 (the bootloader) isn't installed, the system cannot boot. To fix this, you will need to boot from a live cd, that is, booting from the installation disc and selecting "try ubuntu". Then open a terminal window (search for "terminal") and issue this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

This will open a sort of wizard with several options. You can leave the text fields at the default value, but make sure to select the correct drive when you are asked. You will need to select the primary virtual hard drive, which most likely would be /dev/sda (not sda1). Look at the size of the drive to make sure that it matches.

After doing this, grub2 will be installed. Please note that this requires a working installation of ubuntu, so if it fails, try reinstalling. Also, there might be several boot options in a menu during boot (the grub2 menu), in which case you will need to find the right one. Once you have booted the virtual machine from the hard disk, you can eject the CD and run the above command again. I'm not completely sure about this last step, and it might not be necessary. Make sure to remove the CD before trying to boot the new installation.